# Resizing a marquee with an image

Tags: html, marquee

I have a marquee 
like this

```
<marquee scrollamount="10" direction="right" behavior="alternate">
<img src="img/Banner.png"/>
</marquee>
```

It looks fine on normal browser but on the phone the banner is much to large.

I tried

```
<img src="img/Banner.png" style="width:30%"/>
```

but it sets the marquee starting point out side of the screen on the horizontal axis(like -200 x) and the end point almost in the middle of the screen. varies from size to size

I have thought of a solution where I would create multiple images with different sizes and if the screen is in a certain range of size it must load that specific image but I really don't want to go this direction
(if all else fails I will probably have to)

any help or direction?

Comment: You should have your `css` styling for your desktop browser and another `css` styling for mobile browser

Comment: I was hoping their would be a different answer :(.

Comment: I would recommend not using `<marquee>` because it's obsolete and support for it will disappear. Use css keyframes instead to accomplish a similar effect (rolling image) and then you will have a lot more control over it with css. Here's a answer I've given to another question which might prove helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38350596/2003702

Comment: `marquee` is deprecated by w3c and classified in the html5 recommendation as a [non-conforming feature](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#obsolete) due to it's proprietary nature. You shouldn't use it, and should not expect browsers to support this functionality.

Comment: @TheThirdMan what do you suggest?

Comment: Use javascript or jquery to script your own animation, or use a javascript/jquery replacement for the marquee functionality - but either way, don't use `marquee`, as you're literally part of the problem, not the solution, because as long as people implement this functionality, browsers will likely support it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer was given by thepio in the comments i just followed the link and created this. worked for me hope this helps.

```
<style> 
  @keyframes movediv {
    0% { margin-left: 0%; }
    50% { margin-left: 60%; }
    100% { margin-left: 0%; }
  }
</style>

<img src="img/Banner.png" style="height: auto;animation:movediv 8s linear infinite;
max-width: 40%/>
```

If someone wants to re-use this you will just have to tweak the 60% and the 40%

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem seems to be completely independent to the marquee object - all you need is to style your `img` element to adjust to the container size it's in:

```
img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

You could tackle this with media queries, but there is really no reason to if all you want to do is have the image stay within the screen's bounds.

Comment: Thank you for the try. But it didn't seem to work. it still made the image go into -100 x(past the left viewpoint) and it made it very large in comparison to other objects(but that i could fix by reducing image size).